# What does "a cross between the Parthenon and the Reichstag" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

In Gerard Durrell's The Whispering Land I ran into the sentence below:

> At that precise moment we were heading towards the massive building that looked like a cross between the Parthenon and the Reichstag in whose interior lurked the most formidable enemy of sanity and liberty in Argentina: the Aduana, or Customs.

May I ask what "cross between Parthenon and the Reichstag" means here? I guess there might be some cultural implication behind this but I cannot find anything after searching extensively.

Comment: I'm guessing that architecturally it has features of both.  [Parthenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenon) [Reichstag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_building)

Comment: @HotLicks I just found that _a cross between_ could mean _A mixture or compromise of two things_ in Oxford dictionary. Now it makes perfect sense as these two buildings have something in common. Thanks!

Comment: "Cross", in the sense of this idiom, likely is a metaphorical reference to "cross breeding" -- the inter-breeding of two species of plant or animal.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes. Previously I fixated on the literal meaning of cross and thus get myself confused over it. `Cross breeding` would make sense and the sentence is easy to understand now. It's the typical satiric the author used in his book.

Comment: @XintingWANG  Saying that "A is a cross between B and C" does not always imply that B and C are similar in any way. Indeed some of the most striking uses of this type of description are ones where B and C are very different. The use of this type of comparison is usually a derogatory comment on the nature or design of A often, as in the case of the Aduana, implying unnecessary grandiosity. Its use isn't restricted to buildings either, for instance it would be possible to refer to a [Humvee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humvee) as "a cross between a jeep and a gun emplacement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parthenon is a Greek Temple that is distinguished by its thick pillars which surround the perimeter to support the structure.

[image]

The Reichstag is a German political building that is well known for its iconic glass dome constructed on the top and its parliamentarian style.

[image]

When the author said **cross between Parthenon and the Reichstag**, he might have implied that the building was a parliamentarian type building supported by pillars, since **cross between** means a *mixture of*.